# How do you use gdb to debug your code?

Tags: debugging, gdb

As a developer, how do you use gdb to track down bugs within your code?  What techniques tricks do you use to make your life easier?

Comment: I make my life easier by using an IDE that integrates GDB!  ;)

Comment: Which is nice when it's an option.  I'm told my work will join the 21st century in a year or two.  Still, it's always useful to know how to do something manually to benefit from all the features, such as running your own functions with variables from the current point in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Some hints:

- use a graphical frontend (kdbg is quite good, ddd is at least better than command-line gdb, kdevelop has a nice gdb frontend but has some bgs, nemiver looks quite nice as well but is still in the works)
- make sure to have debug symbols and source code for all important parts (your own code and also some system libs)

  - on RedHat, you can install the -debuginfo packages to make both symbols and source code magically appear in the debugger - really cool because you can looks into libc function calls etc.
  - on Debian/Ubuntu, you can install the -dbg packages to get symbols; installing appropriate source files for system packages seems to be difficult, though
- I tend to add assert() and abort() calls in places that should not be reached, or in places that I want to study (some kind of heavy-weight breakpoint)
- ideally the assert() or abort() calls should be wrapped in some method or macro that only enables them in Debug releases, or even better that only enables them if a certain env var is set
- install a signal handler for SIGSEGV and SIGABRT; personally I check if a certain env var is set before installing the handlers; and in the handler I execute a hardcoded external command which usually lives somewhere in ~/.local/bin/; that command might then start kdbg and attach it to the crashing app. Voila, debugger pops up the moment your app does something bad.
- If you use unit tests, you could similarly attach a debugger whenever a test case fails, to inspect the app then.

Comment: Actually asserts are normally removed when building without debugging (-g). From ASSERT(3): "If  the  macro NDEBUG was defined at the moment <assert.h> was last included, the macro assert() generates no code, and hence does nothing at all."

Comment: I'm not sure I would call that "normally". I usually keep my asserts, and I also think the very fact that you have to use the NDEBUG macro (as opposed to, say, not defining a macro "DEBUG") hints that the designers of assert agreed that asserts usually should stay.

Answer (score 2):

In general you find something that isn't how it should be, and work backwards until you understand why.

The most obvious is the most useful:  Setting a breakpoint on a function or line number and walking through the code line by line.

Another handy tip is to have show functions for all your structures/objects even if they are never used in your program, because you can run these functions from within gdb:

```
gdb> p show_my_struct(struct)

My custom display of Foo:
   ...
```

Watchpoints can be really handy too, but may slow down your program a lot. These break the flow when the value of a variable or address changes.:

```
gdb> watch foo
Watchpoint4: foo
gdb>
```

Comment: Why not simply "p my_struct", instead of "p show_my_struct(my_struct)"?

Comment: Because you can decode the flags field, run validation code, etc.  It's not simply a dump of the values of the structure, you instead can dump the meaning, including relevant objects that are pointed to.  For example, if obj1 has a list of obj2s, then you could nest a show of all the obj2s in there.

Answer (score 2):

One particularly useful feature of gdb is its ability to inspect the final state of a program that's crashed.

To inspect a crash dump (or core file, as it's more commonly called), start gdb as follows:

<kbd>gdb <program-name> <core-file></kbd>

For example:

<kbd>gdb a.out core</kbd>

Upon running this command on a core file, gdb will tell you how the program terminated and display where in the program the error occurred:

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x08048364 in foo () at foo.c:4
4         *x = 100;
```

In the example above, you can see that the program terminated with a segmentation fault while trying to assign a value to a pointer.  By typing <kbd>backtrace</kbd> (or <kbd>bt</kbd> or <kbd>where</kbd>) at gdb's prompt, you can view the program's complete backtrace:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x08048364 in foo () at foo.c:4
#1  0x0804837f in main () at foo.c:9
```

At this point, you know that `main()` called `foo()` and `foo()` crashed on line 4 while trying to assign a value to `*x`.  Many times, this provides enough information to allow you to fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Geany](http://www.geany.org).

Answer (score 1):

I do a lot of parallel-program dev, so I've found that using a simple wrapper in python/ruby that allows me to have gdb attached to all processes on all nodes and communicating back to me is extraordinarily helpful (I haven't found a better way if anyone knows of one, not to hijack the thread, though...)

I'm not sure how experienced the OP is, so:

The GDB docs are pretty nice and all encompassing.  The first chapter is a good introduction to all the basics.

http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/

Although not gdb, they are related:
I've personally found that breaking complex lines down to aid in determining which statements are erroring helps.

Also, Valgrind (http://valgrind.org/) is really nice/usefull for tackling buffer-overflows and the like (I haven't had luck with gdb for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Basic but very useful - Use the [text gui](http://davis.lbl.gov/Manuals/GDB/gdb_21.html) with the option -tui.

Comment: You can activate the gdb tui mode by using the CTRL-X CTRL-A

Answer (score 0):

Use ddd, a visual front-end for gdb. It lets you do things easily with a few mouse clicks and visualise how the code works, plus in the debugger console you have an intercative gdb.